# Is it possible to use same workflow for multiple libraries?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, sharepoint-library

I have created two workflows for Library **Products**. I have created a template to use same library on different sub-site.

Will these two workflow work as expected on other libraries which I have created using **Product** template? If not then what do I need to do in such scenarios?

I am working on SharePoint 2013 and using SharePoint Designer to create workflows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not include workflow when you are saving a list/library as template. Only data can be included into template. In this scenario, you can create reusable workflow and activate them in sub-sites. Finally you will be able to use this workflow with your lists/libraries that are created based on this template. If you are not familiar with reusable workflow, then have a look

1. [Reusable and Globally Reusable Workflows in SharePoint 2010](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70867/Reusable-and-Globally-Reusable-Workflows-in-ShareP)
2. [Walkthrough: Import a SharePoint Designer Reusable Workflow into
   Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231580.aspx)

Comment: Comment will be appreciated in case of down  vote. Otherwise, I will think that knives in donkey's hand!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have to check "Document Version" and need to send respective email. So, on which content type I need to create Reusable workflow??

Answer (score 0):

Re-usable workflows will, in most cases lack the stuff you have access to while working on a list workflow (e.g. custom columns, specific content types made for list/lib etc.). If you have an array of sharepoint lists or libraries which are made using one particular template you cannot use one workflow with them - even if it was carried over correctly with a library. In true, that workflow is still associated with a library you saved a template. 
Well, you can use that workflow but it will be a snapshot copy of a workflow when you saved your initial lib/list as a template. If it works and you are happy with the logic, then fine. Just note that every change/publish on a workflow will not cascade down to the libraries.

I cannot see any other way as creating a new workflow for each library (in my case 27 of them!) and copying and pasting the steps from your initial workflow.
You then have to update each and individual workflow with e.g. re-setting specific content types etc.

It would be nice to have one copy of a workflow, associated with multiple lists. One update would publish changes to all of them. This does not seem to be possible if you want to go deep with your workflow logic. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Reusable workflow for that. After that you can add workflow to another list also.

Comment: Hi, what's up? There is a same solution below!

Comment: It is better if you give short answer. Just writing a para will confuse users

Comment: Ohh really! You did not see the comment option yet for short answer I guess.